# Why does angular $compile a form not give me the named elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple test case, yet I cannot access the elements via the scope.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

  describe('testing directive form', function() {
  var form, scope;
  beforeEach(function () {
      module('app');
      inject(function ($compile,$rootScope) {
          var html = '<div><form name="myForm"><input type="text" name="field1"></input><input type="password" name="field2"></input></form></div>';
          $rootScope;
          form = angular.element(html);
          $compile(form)($rootScope);
          scope = form.scope();
          scope.myForm.field1.$setValidity('foo',false);
          scope.myForm.field2.$setValidity('length',false);
      });
  });
  it('have form and elements invalid', function(){
      scope.myForm.field1.$valid.should.be.false;
      scope.myForm.field2.$valid.should.be.false;
      scope.myForm.$valid.should.be.false;
  });
});
```

Yet the line `scope.myForm.field1` evaluated to `undefined`. `scope.myForm` is fine, but not `scope.myForm.field1`. Why is that?

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b67qqktk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to digest your scope:

```
$compile(form)($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
```

And you need to have models for you inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2" ng-model="field2">
```

Comment: I didn't need the `$digest()` because I am just compiling, not setting scope variables, but the `ng-model` was it! Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b67qqktk/13/